# Do you say "to kick something/somebody over" to mean "​to make somebody/something fall to the ground by kicking them"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

We often say "**to push / knock the chair over**" to mean "**​to make somebody/something fall to the ground by pushing / hitting it**" respectively.

Would we say "**to kick something/somebody over**" to mean "**​to make somebody/something fall to the ground by kicking them**", which is similar to saying "**to push / knock somebody/something over**"?

Comment: Accoprding to NGrams, the four most common words preceding ***over the traces*** are ***kick, kicked, kicking, kicks***. You can ***kick, shove, boot,...** it over* with the "topple" sense, but all those (and ***push*** and ***knock***) can equally well mean ***over here/there***. Some verbs, such as *He **barged** it over*, can ***only*** mean "toppled".

Comment: @Fumblefingers You can certainly _kick an object over_, but I believe _kick over the traces_ is a different sense of _over_, the traces in question being part of a draught horse's harness.